# PC automatically wakes up after turning on light

Tags: windows, usb, sleep

That's really strange thing that when I put my PC into sleep my PC goes into sleep mode but when I turn on my room lights or any electronic component in it, it automatically wakes up. When I tried to figure out this magical problem using `powercfg -lastwake` command this showed as a result:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see it shows USB Root hub as problem which wakes it up. How can I fix this by not allowing USB Root hub from waking up my PC.

Comment: I think that's not a reason as my pc can't do this kind of things.By light i mean any electrical item e.g .fan,fridge,etc..I think power fluctuation is cause of this problem.So my question is how do i stop USB root HUB from waking up my pc.

Comment: Like mentioned in the other answer, it seems to be some USB device what is getting triggered by your light switch.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you have at least your USB keyboard and USB mouse connected to your PC ports? What else is connected to USB ports?

Answer (score 3):

Look to see if you have anything connected to a outlet that is controlled by the light switch in the room. If something turns on a device connected to the computer it might be waking up the system if the BIOS settings are set to wake up on USB activity.

Also if you have a ball mouse or something else that could be triggered as movement from external light sources than this might cause it too.

Unplug each USB device and recreate. When you find what device is doing it then you can track it as to why it is causing the computer to wake up.

Comment: How can i disable waking up from usb activity via BIOS?

Comment: @Under_stand most likely it's phrased like: `Allow Keyboard to wake PC` or similar.

Comment: ball mouse? Do t you mean optical mouse. A ball mouse would have to be physically moved.